# selenium script is not running

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 14991
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1573970978.437][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-JCFLT7B', ip: '192.168.1.107', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurs  because your chrome browser version is not compatible with the chrome driver version. Check your chrome browser version and then install chrome driver from the below location based on  your os.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

**for e.g:** 
I am using `Version 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)` with windows and currently using  `chromedriver_win32.zip`

[image]